# Can I encode a string to an integer in a way that preserves lexicographic string closeness?

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashcode

I would like to encode strings of varying length (typically 1-100 characters) to integers in a way that strings which are lexicographically similar (they would be close together in a dictionary) result in integers that are close together, while further ensuring that these integers are reasonably evenly distributed across the range of possible integer values.

I recognize that ensuring an even distribution may require some kind of survey of the possible strings prior to encoding them.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: How random is your closeness? If you want exact numbers, the simplest hash which does this is the index of the string inside of the dictionary.

Comment: Blender, yes I was thinking along those lines.  Take a random sampling of,  2^16 of the strings and sort it into a dictionary.  Then, for any string the index in this dictionary is the first 16 bits of the integer hash, then second 16 bits is a hash of the entire string.

Comment: Can't a string be lexicographically equidistant from > 2 other strings?  If so, then your goal is impossible, because each integer is only equidistant from 2 other integers.

Comment: mbeckish, I'm not sure it matters, since I'm really only concerned about preserving the ordering.

Comment: "A random sampling of 2^16 of the strings" may be improved to a random sampling of 10*2^16 and then deleting 9 samples out of each 10. This will distribute strings in dictionary more evenly.

Comment: @sanity - Nevermind - the answer to my question is "no".  I was thinking of Levenshtein distance, not lexicographical ordering.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here, ultimately? Perhaps there's another way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Compressed keys** might be useful here. The idea is to compare a set of strings and remove all bits, that are similar. Which produces a set of almost unique keys, small enough to fit in an integer. See chapter 6 of ["FAST: Fast Architecture Sensitive Tree Search on Modern CPUs and GPUs"](http://wiki.epfl.ch/edicpublic/documents/Candidacy%20exam/kim.pdf).

Described algorithm does not always preserve lexicographical order, but may be augmented to do it.

**Edit**:

More general approach is to split string characters to independent parts (if possible), then determine these parts' probabilities, and apply [arithmetic coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding).

**Edit2**:

To fit more of the string in the compressed key it may be preferrable to use some sort of [entropy encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_encoding), where encoding of a character involves values of several, but no more than 1 .. 2 previous characters (improving compressibility too much will degrade performance). Or, if integer key should be short enough (like 16 bits), it is better to use entropy methods to precalculate all keys and put them to the collection ordered by strings; in this case encoding prefix may be much longer.

Answer (score 4):

A general approach would be using the first n characters in your string, zero-byte-padded as necessary, as an integer number. Reduce your alphabet accordingly, and you should achieve a fairly dense packing. Example:
Assume your input alphabet is Base64 with / representing the end of string. You'd hash the string 'word/'
 by setting the six highest-most bits of your integer to 48, the next six to 40, and so on. Pad with two zeros, and you have got an exact representation in a 32 bit integer.

Lexicographically close words will have similar beginnings and thereby similar most-significant bits.

Naturally, words longer than 5 characters have hash collisions, but that can't be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are pretty tight. How about using a minimal perfect hash function? This ensures that if you give the strings in lexicographic order:

```
s1 < s2 < s3 < s4 < ... < sN
```

they will be mapped to consecutive integers in the range [0..N-1]. See these papers:

http://didawiki.cli.di.unipi.it/lib/exe/fetch.php/magistraleinformaticanetworking/ae/ae2010/01_appoggiomg-minordhash.pdf

http://vigna.dsi.unimi.it/ftp/papers/MonotoneMinimalPerfectHashing.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  Assume you came up with some function to map strings to integers.  Then let's say you mapped the first input string, s1, to an integer, i1, and mapped the second input string, s2, to i2.  The problem then lies with the input strings that follow.   You only have room for |i2 - i1| more input strings that fall between s1 and s2.  But there's no way to guarantee that you won't receive more than |i2 - i1| strings that fall between s1 and s2, at least not practically (you'd have to use integers on the order of 26^100 for strings of a single case with up to 100 characters).

Comment: This isn't correct. Lexicographical strings are ordered. Any countable ordered set can be mapped bijectively onto a subset of the integers preserving the order. I think the original question is more about an algorithm to achieve this efficiently, than about the existence of such a hash function (indeed, there are infinitely many such).

Comment: @user - I think you are referring to the mathematical concept of integers.  I was referring to the typical computer representation of integers (32-bit or 64-bit).

Comment: It doesn't matter. Here's a simple hash function that will achieve just that. Suppose all our strings are at most n characters long, and the characters take the values 0, ..., k. So each string looks like (a1, a2, ..., an), with each ai in range (0, ..., k). Then given such a string, convert it to linear index using (a1, a2, ..., an)-->a1*k^(n-1)+a2*k^(n-2)+...+an. That's your hash function.

Comment: @user - I wasn't assuming that the strings were given in some order - I thought the input was a stream of strings, so each string needs to be encoded without knowing anything about the remaining strings.

Comment: You don't need to assume that they are given in any order. See my edited comment above.

Comment: By the way, the OP was asking whether such an algorithm exists in principle (it is obvious that every algorithm is subject to hardware limitations, which is what you seem to be pointing out). The answer is yes, such an algorithm exists. In fact, any perfect monotone hash function will do, but, again, just like any algorithm, it is certainly subject to hardware limitations.

Comment: @user - Did you read my post? " at least not practically (you'd have to use integers on the order of 26^100 for strings of a single case with up to 100 characters)"  - which is the same as your edited comment "a1*k^(n-1)...".

Comment: I realize that. The question was not about hardware limitations, but about an admissible algorithm. The answer is: there exist such algorithms. One would have to be somewhat limited in the mental abilities to not be able to understand that the total number of possible alphabetical strings of length 100 (using the Latin alphabet) is 26^100. If you claim that your answer was dedicated to pointing this out, then I retreat with the understanding that you're only pointing out the obvious.

Comment: @user - My point was not about hardware limitations - it was about the extreme amount of collisions you can expect from squeezing 100 character input string into a 32-bit hash, especially because of the constraint that lexicographically similar strings should be mapped closely together.  But I think enough has been said about this topic.